# Check first implementation of a feature in java

Tags: java

I wanted to use a particular option `-DentityExpansionLimit` in java using a jdk and I was unsuccessful on an old version. I there anyway I can see which was the version this option was first implemented on? I was unable to find any answers and was hoping there is like a guide where an option was first implemented or even all the new features implemented for each version. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it was first introduced in **Java 1.4**.
**Reference Links**:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/xml/jaxp/JAXP-Compatibility_160.html
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/relnotes-139182.html

**As per the link:**
**New system property to limit entity expansion**
The entityExpansionLimit system property lets existing applications constrain the total number of entity expansions without recompiling the code. The parser throws a fatal error once it has reached the entity expansion limit. (By default, the limit is set to 64000.)

To set the entity expansion limit using the system property, use an option like the following on the java command line: -DentityExpansionLimit=100000

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option is to use google and check the release notes of each version.

Example: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-429209.html

In your case, seems like your flag comes from [JSDK v1.4.2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/relnotes-139182.html)